# Cancel an MSI without showing the "installation interrupted" dialog

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I am wondering if it is possible to have the "Cancel" button on my welcome screen completely quit the installer without showing the final "Installation interrupted" dialog. I consider this redundant when the user hasn't even begun the installation yet.

I still want the dialog to be shown if the user cancels an installation that *has already been started*, but not if the installation hasn't been started (which is the case if the Cancel button is hit on the welcome screen).

I have tried various things but I lack a proper understanding of how Windows Installer works to fathom a solution.

**Update:** Got it to work! I ended up using a combination of the two suggestions--I wish I could give you both the answer, but I'll give it to ray as he has the lowest rep. But I'll upvote them both. Here's how I did it (I'm still surprised it works):

I used the `Publish` element as ray suggested, but instead of invoking an event (there's no event called "Finish"), I set a property, "AbortInstall" to `1`:

```
<Publish Dialog="SimpleDlg"
                    Control="Cancel"
                    Property="AbortInstall"
                    Value="1">1</Publish>
```

I did this in my custom set file WixUI_Simple.wxs under Wix/Fragment/UI

Then, inside UserExit.wxs I modified the InstallUISequence as follows:

```
<InstallUISequence>
            <Show Dialog="Simple_UserExit"
                    OnExit="cancel">NOT AbortInstall = 1</Show>
        </InstallUISequence>
```

...which is the idea suggested by Christopher.

Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this so it might not work in the slightest, but what the hell.

You probably can create a Publish element for the WelcomeDlg on the Cancel button control like so:

```
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Cancel" Event="Finish" Value="Exit">1</Publish>
```

Let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at your InstallUISequence table:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369543(VS.85).aspx

Notice the special dialogs with a sequence of -1, -2 and -3. Notice that you can also put a condition on the dialogs.   With a little creatavity you can use a property as a flag to determine whether your install ever really began and prevent or show the dialog in question.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI & fun.
How to **hide Exit dialog** in [wix](/questions/tagged/wix):
In your custom **WixUI_xxxxx.wxs** under `<UI>` tag place

```
<Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="MyNewDlg" Control="Ok" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="1">1</Publish>
```

Under `<Product>` tag insert:

```
<Property Id="ExitSuccess" Value="1" />
```

And

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Show Dialog="MyNewDlg" After="SomeAction">Installed</Show>
  <Show Dialog="ExitDialog" OnExit="success">NOT ExitSuccess = 1</Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```

That's all.