# I need to upgrade Wix 3.7 to 3.10.2

Tags: wix, wix3.10

I need to upgrade Wix 3.7 to 3.10.2. I am  currently using WiX.3.7\setupbld.exe to create the setup in the project file. Just installed the Wix 3.10.2 toolset in to my PC. Couldn't find any of  setup.exe, setupbld.exe or SetupBuilder.dll which I used before in the folder WiX.3.7 which commited with source control. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate question here: [WiX 3.8: Create an .EXE Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119030/wix-3-8-create-an-exe-installer)

Basically, if you want to use setup.exe, setupbld.exe, and SetupBuilder.dll from WiX 3.7, just copy them from the WiX 3.7 "bin" folder into the new WiX version's "bin" folder.

**Edit**
Alternatively, you can try to create a simple Bootstrapper Application using WiX Burn.

Here is an example: [WiX: How do I get the MSI's dialogs to show, when wrapped in Burn/EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374234/wix-how-do-i-get-the-msis-dialogs-to-show-when-wrapped-in-burn-exe)

More documentation on how to build the bundle can be found here: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/

Comment: Reason we are updating to Wix 3.10.2 is avoid "vulnerability known as DLL hijacking" will it be solved when copying from WiX 3.7.

Comment: If DLL hijacking is an issue, "Don't use EXE installers" https://packetstormsecurity.com/files/135343/WiX-Toolset-DLL-Hijacking.html

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an alternative approach, and that is to use Burn.